# Почему простая проверка числа на простоту в цикле сделана до sqrt(n)?

Tags: c++

Нашел в интернете код, но никак не пойму почему именно в цикле до `sqrt(n)`.
Объясните, пожалуйста.

```
{
int n;
bool flag = true;
for (i = 2; i < sqrt(n); i++) {
  if (n % i == 0) {
    flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Только надо не `< sqrt`, а `<= sqrt` и как только выполнится `flag = false;` можно покидать цикл (не простое).

Comment: И маленькое улучшение. Проверить, что n != 2 (2 -- простое), проверить, что n четное (не простое), а потом проверять только на нечетных, т.е. `for (i = 3; i <= sqrtn; i += 2) ...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если у числа есть множитель больше `sqrt(n)`, то у него есть второй множитель, меньший чем `sqrt(n)`, а мы до этого все меньшие множители уже проверили, их нет.
Значит проверку надо останавливать на `sqrt(n)`.